# Getting Exception when filename has spaces in File.WriteAllBytes() c#

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.io.file

I have to use File.WriteAllBytes() to store the file contents.
If `file.Filename` is a string without spaces it works fine (like "abc","sample"). But if `file.FileName` comes with values like *"power bi report", "March report"* ,throws error.

```
File.WriteAllBytes($"D:\\PowerBi Console\\PowerBiConsole\\{file.FileName}.pdf",file.FileContents);
```

`file` is a `FileModel` instance and

```
public class FileModel
    {
        public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Error: [image: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect]

Comment: It's not the spaces. It's the colons. Maybe you should check what characters are allowed in a file name. This is not a programming issue but just a simple computer use issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the space(s), but the colon. A `:` is not valid in a file name. You need to replace it with e.g. dashes.

Note that if you use `date.ToString()` to generate (part of) a filename, it gets tricky, because different cultures use different characters as time or date separators. Many of those are not valid in a file name. You can find the list of invalid characters in a filename by querying the static method `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`.